# ABOUT button giving error when clicked

Tags: android

I have create an about button for sudoku and set the `OnClickListener` on it, made the class called About.java and about.xml and added ........... in manifest.xml

About.java

```
package org.example.btg;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class About extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);
    }
}
```

about.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/about_text" />
</ScrollView>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.example.btg"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".BrainTrainingGame"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name=".About"
        android:label="@string/about_title" >
    </activity>
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
            </action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity> 
    </application>
</manifest>
```

btg.java

```
View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
aboutButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
exitButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.about_button:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
```

The logcat appears when the error comes is as follows:

```
03-01 12:16:51.062: D/AndroidRuntime(684): Shutting down VM
03-01 12:16:51.062: W/dalvikvm(684): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.btg/org.example.btg.BrainTrainingGame}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at org.example.btg.BrainTrainingGame.onCreate(BrainTrainingGame.java:21)
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-01 12:16:51.126: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  ... 11 more
03-01 12:21:51.292: I/Process(684): Sending signal. PID: 684 SIG: 9
```

The help wouldbe greatly appreciated!

Its still not working.

Comment: it says "THE BTG HAS STOPPED UNEXPECTEDLY" and there a "Force Close" Button

Comment: Please paste the logcat you get from this error.

Comment: 03-01 12:16:51.062: W/dalvikvm(684): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

Comment: We need some more information than just one line. It would be nice if you could update your question with the whole stacktrace. Then we will be able to see what lines of your code are causing problems.

Comment: i ave copy pasted the LogCat of th error that comes. Hope that helps

Comment: What is on line 21 in BrainTrainingGame.java? org.example.btg.BrainTrainingGame.onCreate(BrainTrainingGame.java:21)

Comment: Try using Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), About.class);
then Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
in onClick() of your btg.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the About section in your manifest. You cannot have an activity defined within another activity:

```
<activity
  android:name=".BrainTrainingGame"
  android:label="@string/app_name" >

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
    </action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".About"
  android:label="@string/about_title" >
</activity>
```

Comment: I have done that but now when i run it is not showing button that i have created anymore and say "the btg has stop unexpectedly"